# How do you strip leading spaces in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to strip leading spaces from a column in Oracle. I've Googled but haven't found any answers except to write my own function which I'd like to avoid.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rls=en&hs=ja1&q=How+do+you+strip+leading+spaces+in+Oracle&aq=f&oq=&aqi=

Comment: Touché. Though now this page is the second result ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can user [LTRIM](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions083.htm#i77875) Oracle function:

```
SQL> select ltrim(' hello world') from dual;

LTRIM('HELLOWORLD')
-------------------
hello world
```

For ending spaces you can use [RTRIM](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions141.htm#i1018967). And for more options check out [TRIM](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm#i79689).

Answer (score 3):

use the [trim](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php) function removes all specified characters either from the beginning or the ending of a string.

```
trim( [ leading | trailing | both  [ trim_character ]  ]   string1 )
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE table SET field = TRIM(field);

Answer (score -1):

Update TABLE_NAME
set FIELD_NAME = TRIM(COLUMN_NAME)